# How do I incorporate javascript on css editor on wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

So on my site (http://braunweiss.net) you can see that I have sticky side buttons. My boss wants me to add another button that would allow me to remove the buttons from the screen like one you can find on http://www.astcorporation.com/erp.html . I was thinking that I could maybe try to use javascript in my css editor (since that's the only editor I can access on wordpress) and have it so that when I click on the minimize button, I can do a **display:none** on the other buttons.

If there are suggestions as to other ways I can execute such functions, it'll be great. I can access the php files of the wordpress plugin I use called "sticky side buttons", and can modify the php, but unfortunately I'm not familiar with php.

Thanks!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I really hate using Javascript to style CSS.  It feels very hacky and it's easy to lose track of your changes.

Unfortunately it does sound like a reasonable approach given your constraints.

Otherwise, here's how you can do it by binding this function to a button:

```
function myFunction() {
   var x = document.getElementById('ssb-container');
   if (x.style.display === 'none') {
       x.style.display = 'block';
   } else {
       x.style.display = 'none';
   }
}
```

Now what I would do is add an animation to the css.   I'll leave that as an excersize for OP.  There are lots of resources online :)

Cheers